# Cocoa, Obejective-c how to compare output from SSH to NSString

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, ssh, compare

how to compare 2 string, when i got one string from SSH output the code parts:

```
NSString *response = [session.channel execute:@"date" error:&error];
NSLog(@"Output: %@", response);
NSString *day = @"Saturday";
```

the output is = Saturday

and i can't compare with this:

```
if (response == day)
    NSLog (@"day equals response");
else
    NSLog (@"day does not equal response");

if ([response isEqualToString:day])
    NSLog (@"day equals response");
else
    NSLog (@"day does not equal response");
```

It's always fails, maby i need to convert response or day , or use something diffrent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the line at the end of the response:

```
response = [response stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```